# Using rsync with StrictHostKeyChecking and find files older than 5 minutes from remote

Tags: rsync, shell, find

I would like to use rsync to sync my files from remote to a local directory. Therefor I use *StrictHostKeyChecking* so that there's no need to enter a password.

Now I would like to only sync files older than 5 minutes. I thought to use

```
find /path/to/folder/ -type f -mmin +5
```

How can I integrate it into my remote procedure?

```
rsync -e "./ssh -i %syncclientkey% -o  'StrictHostKeyChecking no'" syncusr@%syncsrv:path/to/source path/to/destination
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StrictHostKeyChecking` has nothing to do with password-less authentication. It purpose is to issue a forward-confirmed reverse DNS to be sure that you are really connection to the intended server, and that no DNS-level hijacking is used to misdirect you to another server.

To use pubkey authentication, you had to follow these steps:

1. create a new public / private keys using `ssh-keygen`
2. copy the pubkey to the remote server using `ssh-copy-id`

Regarding the second part of your question, `rsync` by itself is not capable of time-based selection. You had to generate the filelist via `find` and pipe it to `rsync`.

For example: `find /path/to/folder/ -type f -mmin +5 -print0 | rsync -files-from=- -from0 syncusr@%syncsrv:path/to/source path/to/destination`

However, as `rsync` is extremely efficient in transfering only changed files/deltas, maybe you can entirely skip the file-selection step and simply synchronize the entire folder each 5 minutes. `rsync` will sync/transfer only the changed files (with a 5 minute interval, this means that only files changed in the last 5 minutes will be synchronized).